# Dokku use subdomain as global

Tags: dokku

I'm trying to use Dokku on my own VPS and deploy my apps on subdomains of my third-level root domain.

For example if my Dokku global vhost is `server.domain.tld`, I want to have my app to be deployed to `my-app.server.domain.tld`.

For the moment I did the following:

```
$ dokku domains:add-global server.domain.tld

$ dokku domains:set-global server.domain.tld
```

And then deployed my app:

```
$ git remote add dokku dokku@server.domain.tld:my-app

$ git push dokku master
remote: =====> Application deployed:
remote:        http://my-app.server.domain.tld
```

But when I go to `http://my-app.server.domain.tld` the server doesn't respond, I have to browse `http://server.domain.tld` to see my app.

```
$ dokku domains:report
=====> my-app domains information
       Domains app enabled:           true
       Domains app vhosts:            my-app.server.domain.tld
       Domains global enabled:        true
       Domains global vhosts:         server.domain.tld
```

Does Dokku support subdomains as global domain?
Do I have to use a specific config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging into Dokku GitHub issues, I found:

- [Are nested subdomains supported in Dokku? #394](https://github.com/dokku/dokku/issues/394)
- [Cannot access app by domain name #2574](https://github.com/dokku/dokku/issues/2574)

**You need to add a wildcard DNS record (*.server.domain.tld)**

[Dokku DNS documentation with more infos](http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/networking/dns/)